# Localizing Xceed DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, xceed-datagrid

I am trying to find a way how to localize or remove "items" text in Xceed DataGrid for WPF (Community version), which is displayed automatically. Anybody knows how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the "items" label that is hardcoded in the [Group](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-datagrid-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.v5.9~Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Group.html)'s `DataTemplate`.

So the solution is to overwrite that `DataTemplate`. It is not so difficult if you use [implicit data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx): just put your `DataTemplate` in the resources of the window with the `DataGridControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">


    <Window.Resources>
        <xcdg:StringFormatMultiConverter x:Key="stringFormatMultiConverter" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="customGroupTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Title}" ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.TitleTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.TitleTemplateSelector}" />
                <TextBlock Text=": " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.ValueTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.ValueTemplateSelector}">
                    <ContentPresenter.Content>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource stringFormatMultiConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Value" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ValueStringFormat" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ValueStringFormatCulture" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ContentPresenter.Content>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <TextBlock Text=" (" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Name="suffixRun" Text="položky" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text=")" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="1" Binding="{Binding ItemCount}">
                    <Setter TargetName="suffixRun" Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="položka" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xcdg:Group}">
            <ContentControl Name="groupContentPresenter" Focusable="False" 
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource customGroupTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

I sniffed the default template with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), then I created my own one with the word "items" translated.

I hope it can help you.